# How to hide form select option when an option is nil rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've got the following form select:

```
<%= f.select(:size_requested, [@item.size1, @item.size2, @item.size3, @item.size4, @item.size5, @item.size6, @item.size7, @item.size8, @item.size9, @item.size10], {}, { class: 'form-control quantity-select' }) %>
```

I'm trying to have it where only the sizes that are not nil are presented as options and avoid this:

[image]

When I try things like (@item.size6 if @item.size6) for the options I still have the same issue and the nil options are still visible.  Can anyone lead me in the right direction to solve this in a clean way?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You should try to compile the list to display in the controller, then you won't have to rely on the view to make the decision.  In whatever controller method renders this form, add a @sizes var that you can populate with non-nil values.

Comment: Sweet, thanks Joe.  I'm going to give that a shot now.

Comment: I should clarify that the actual logic that determines the contents in the list should be in the Model, but the assignment to the instance var should be in the controller.

Comment: Thanks!  Am going to try this way.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `compact` method to remove nils from an array. For example:

```
[1, nil, 2, nil].compact
```

Also, as a comment on your question suggests, it's a good idea to set up the array in your controller and then reference that in the view rather than performing logic in the view itself.